# Get $webclient.downloadstring to write to text file in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, export

I'm not a programmer/scripter. I just need to get the following script to write to a file:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()

# Create a web client object
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient


# Returns the public IP address
$webClient.DownloadString('http://myip.dnsomatic.com/')
```

I've tried out-file and export-csv but it write a blank file. I'm sure it's something simple...but having no knowledge makes it difficult for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The add-content cmdlet should do what you want.

Assuming `$webClient.DownloadString('http://myip.dnsomatic.com/')` returns a string, try:

```
Add-Content -Path $filename -Value $webClient.DownloadString('http://myip.dnsomatic.com/')
```

Reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347594.aspx

Comment: I get an error, perhaps a space is needed between $webclient and -value ? EDIT: Aah my mistake, dont forget to include $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

Answer (score 9):

You could also use the DownloadFile method:

```
$webClient.DownloadFile('http://myip.dnsomatic.com/', 'c:\ip.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$PublicIP="C:\PublicIP.txt"

$WebClient=New-Object net.webclient

$String=$WebClient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.com") -replace "[^\d\.]"

If (Test-Path $PublicIP) {

    Remove-Item $PublicIP
}

New-Item $PublicIP -type file

Add-Content -Path $PublicIP -Value $String
```