# How can I use HTTP GET in PowerShell?

Tags: http, powershell, http-get

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Get $webclient.downloadstring to write to text file in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365000/get-webclient-downloadstring-to-write-to-text-file-in-powershell) 
> [Powershell http post with .cer for auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116489/powershell-http-post-with-cer-for-auth)

I have an SMS system that provides me the ability to send an SMS from an HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request:

```
http://smsserver/SNSManager/msgSend.jsp?uid&to=smartsms:*+001XXXXXX&msg="text of the message"&encoding=windows-1255
```

I want to enter the details to the text from PowerShell and just surf to this URL.  How can I do it?

Comment: I've nominated for reopen as this seems to be the simplest question that *just* asks about doing a `GET`; the linked 'dupes' ask about writing the result to a file, and doing a post.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://example.com/`

Comment: Related: [PowerShell equivalent of curl](https://superuser.com/q/344927/87805).

Answer (score 57):

In PowerShell v3, have a look at the [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) and [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) e.g.:

```
$msg = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter message"
$encmsg = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($msg)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://smsserver/SNSManager/msgSend.jsp?uid&to=smartsms:*+001XXXXXX&msg=$encmsg&encoding=windows-1255"
```

Comment: In case you want to look at the HTTP response, the output object from `Invoke-WebRequest` leaves much to be desired, though you could output the `RawContent` property which includes the headers. Otherwise `Invoke-RestMethod` has better output.

Answer (score 25):

Downloading Wget is not necessary; the .NET Framework has web client classes built in.

```
$wc = New-Object system.Net.WebClient;
$sms = Read-Host "Enter SMS text";
$sms = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($sms);
$smsResult = $wc.downloadString("http://smsserver/SNSManager/msgSend.jsp?uid&to=smartsms:*+001XXXXXX&msg=$sms&encoding=windows-1255")
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to run `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web` before calling UrlEncode().