# use curl or start in batch file silently

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I've been trying to create a batch file that I can either use curl in or start to basically hit a specific url. But I would like that action to run silently, to no avail. I'm on Vista if that is any sort of important.

I've tried the following:

```
curl -s http://domain.com/page.php

start /B (and /b) "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome" chrome.ext http://domain.com/page.php
```

The start just opens up a chrome browser and goes to the url which is not ideal. And the curl just doesn't seem like it's doing anything.

I am working on a bat file that will be called by a program before other things happen. And that bat file is intended to hit a url, where it would then basically send out an SMS message to a list. But for the sake of resources (memory specifically) I'd like the action to occur without it opening a browser/window.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Cannot go to a url with simple batch. You need en external tool (like curl), but you have to add/install the tool, because curl is not a default cmd command.

Comment: What about using WGET to get the url?

Comment: it is also an external tool.

Comment: You could use a powershell script to call an url -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/13936766/2379343